# need to check the whole domain instead of the single url

Tags: php, mysql, variables

i have this peace of code to validate submissions:

```
 // Check to see if the URL is banned.
         $array=parse_url($contenturl2);
          $domaincheck = $array['host'];
          $domaincheck1 = str_replace("www.", "", $domaincheck);
          $domaincheck2 = "http://".trim($domaincheck1);
          $domaincheck3 = "http://www.".$domaincheck2;


          $query = "select id from banned where (url = '$contenturl' || url = '$contenturl2' || url = '$domaincheck' || url = '$domaincheck1' || url = '$domaincheck2' || url = '$domaincheck3') && url != ''";
          $result = mysql_query($query);
            if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
            {
            $_SESSION['submitstatus'] = "<div class=success><b>Sorry! This domain is banned from our network</div>";
            header('Location: '.$frompage.'');
            exit;
            }
```

At some point its working, but not as it was suposed, because if i add "domain.com/content.html" to the ban list, the url will be banned, but not the domain, when i add the domain "domain.com" to the ban list i want this code to ban all the urls under this domain.

I dont post the whole file here because its really big, but i can post it if you guys request to do so.

The variable $contenturl2 refered on the excerpt i posted have the follow variables related:

$contenturl = clean_string($_POST['contenturl']);

$contenturl2 = strtolower($contenturl);

Whis $contenturl grabs the domains banned from sql.

I really hope someone can give me a clue on how to acomplish this.

Sincerely
Dani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
// Check to see if the URL is banned.
$array=parse_url($contenturl2);
$domaincheck = $array['host'];

$query = "select id from banned where url LIKE '%" . $domaincheck . "%'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    $_SESSION['submitstatus'] = "<div class=success><b>Sorry! This domain is banned from our network</div>";
    header('Location: '.$frompage.'');
    exit;
}
```

This should match all variations of the domain name. Note: you must have the percentage signs around the characters you wish to match.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your solution, im just a bit confused, can you be more specific on where i do have to put the % signs? i understand that must be around the characters i want to match but the problem is that i dont know what characters match what :S sorry im just start learning php, hope you understand

Comment: The characters you are trying to match are the domain name. So, if the domain name is somedomain.com, the query would need to be: $query = "select id from banned where url LIKE '%somedomain.com%'";

Comment: The code above will give you exactly that. And, it will match variations like www.somedomain.com OR somethingelse.somedomain.com OR somedomain.com/internal_page.html

Comment: OK i think i got it, you are saying that i just need to change $query = "select id from banned where (url = '$contenturl' || url = '$contenturl2' || url = '$domaincheck' || url = '$domaincheck1' || url = '$domaincheck2' || url = '$domaincheck3') && url != ''"; with your code?

Comment: No, you don't need all those variations. You just need the query I wrote. Cut all the rest out. I just edited my answer to show you the re-written code.

Comment: Just tested and it works like a charm. Thanks so much for sharing your aknowledge. All the best

Comment: This will also pick up instances where the Domain is a query string parameter.  Additionally, if the value of $array['host'] has a different scheme (http vs https) this query will fail to pick it up.

Comment: Not true Stephan. Test it yourself. He is using parse_url, so the scheme is in the scheme element, not in the host element.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a bit wrong with your scheme for breaking up the url that you are receiving and comparing it with what is in the DB.

I would use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) which would allow you to take only the parts that you care about out of the URL that you receive - rebuild it to be whatever you want it to be, and then check the DB.

There is a lot of important logic that you are missing with your current scheme.  For instance, if a given domain is blocked, should all sub-domains be blocked? ie. if mydomain.com is blocked should www.mydomain.com be blocked?

Comment: Hello and thanks for your advice. Yes thats really what is supsed to be, if i ban domain.com, all urls and subdomains under this domain should be banned. I just dont know how to acomplish this, im really a novice with this. Anyways thanks for your sugestion